# Is there a way to limit access to Attachments based on the Subject field?

Tags: profile, permissions, permission-sets, field-level-security

My organization would like to have the ability to restrict the viewing permissions of certain user in regards to some of the Attachments we add to specific objects. For example, we'd like all Attachments that contain some permutation of "invoice" in their subject line to only be visible to a specific Profile type or Permission Set. I'm not sure if this is possible or not?

Comment: How are these documents attached? Who owns them? Are they currently given a record type? How are they currently shared? What objects are they attached to? Will the user who you don't want to see them own the record they're attached to? Some more specificity to your question would be helpful.

Comment: @crmprogdev

They're attached to a Contact within their "Notes & Attachments" Related List section.
The user who attaches them. It's usually done by one person who would have the access to these documents too.
No record type is given to the attachments.
Everyone that uses the system has access to Contact records so that's how they can see them.
They're attached to a Contact within their "Notes & Attachments" Related List section.
Maybe. All users have the ability to create Contacts but the desired goal is for only users with a higher permission set to be able to see those specific attachments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

I gave this further thought last night after posting and wasn't able to get back to it for an edit.

From looking at the [Object Reference for Attachment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm), it doesn't appear as though you can assign a RecordType to an attachment, but you can make it Private regardless of who attached it or owns it. Someone other than the owner of the record that it's attached to can own the attachment.

My suggestion would be to do the following. Create a sharing rule called "invoices" that you associate with a group called "invoice viewers" who have read only permission on Contact attachments. When a new attachment is created (inserted), read the `Attachment.Name` (convert it to lower case when you do). If the Name field contains `invoice`, make sharing on the new attachment private.

Once it's set to private, use [Criteria Based Sharing Rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_sharing_cbs_about.htm) to share the document with the "invoice viewers" group using the criteria that the lower case value of the text in the `Attachment.Name` field contains 'invoice'.

I'm confident there are several ways of doing this, such as with a trigger and Apex sharing, but below is one way that I think should work well for you.

Use a before insert trigger to make the sharing on the object private based on evaluating the string in the Attachment.Name. Once you do, you can then use Criteria based sharing rules to set the sharing via workflow. Alternatively, once the record has been set to private via the trigger, you could implement Apex Sharing through a trigger.

Check the links I've provided for the "how to" details on implementing Criteria Based Sharing via workflow and here's a few [links](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_apex_sharing_reasons.htm&language=en_US) for [Apex Sharing](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000002813&language=en_US), the latter of which would be for [AfterInsert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm).

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I don't think I can create Sharing Rules and/or Workflow Rules specifically based on attachments of objects. I will probably have to look into Apex Sharing. It's also very possible I just don't know how to make Sharing Rules/Workflow Rules based on Attachments and am happy to hear any advice regarding that as well

Comment: See my edited response.